# Kettle Javascript - Accessing data from another Lookup Step within Transformation

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a transformation that has a complex Javascript transformation in the middle of it.  Within this Javascript I need to send an ID to a lookup step elsewhere in the transformation.  Ie:

[image: Transformation]
Is there a way to send an ID from Javascript in the "Modified Java Script Value" step to the XMLLookup Step to obtain a result from that step within that flow the transformation?

Comment: as far as i understand your problem.
When you define the number of fields into the field name column in modified javascript you will able to access that going forward in any other step in that particular transformation.

Comment: It's more that I want to preload a bunch of lookup data (which needs some transformation prior to being referenced), but within the data that the JS script is modifying, I may need to reference the same Lookup data multiple times - if it were definitely only once, I could just join the lookup into the flow, but it's going to be several times (and in the final solution, there will be two or three lookups that may be referenced by the JS script